# Get an PHP Object or Array in URL link

Tags: php

in this code I want to Get an PHP Object  or Array in URL

```php
$_REQUEST["passwd"]
```

What should I code in URL to send an Obj or Arr?

```
https://test.com/?passwd="{what should I code in this?}"
```

Or Another way can do this with URL?
Thanks for your ANSWER

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to achieve this through url
better approach is to use store object or array in session variable and then fetch session variable on other page
or
post request via submitting a form

Comment: yes,you're right.Because I'm playing a wargame of serverside web-security,so I asked this question.This way is not safe and not well that make me need to study it.

Comment: passing array through url is not possible actually you need to go some other way either via post request or through sessions